# jQuery val() returns empty though element.value returns value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript issue that appears sometimes and sometimes not (inconsistent behavior) ... I can see on Chrome console that when the issue happens, the code:

```
alert( document.getElementById('F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE').value);
```

returns value while the code:

```
var meetingDate22 = $("input[name='F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE']").val();
alert(meetingDate22);
```

that I am using in the code returns empty... this empty string is causing the issue... can any one help with the reason?

Comment: Because `name` != `id`?

Comment: No it has the same name and Id

Comment: I works sometimes

Comment: [mcve] or it didnt happen!

Comment: Double check jquery has finished loading before you try to access `$`?
`$(function(){ var meetingDate22 = $("input[name='F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE']").val(); ... })`

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: can you show the html element ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try using the ID instead of the name, like this:

```
var meetingDate22 = $("#F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE").val();
alert(meetingDate22);
```

Comment: @osamayaccoub Is it possible you have two elements with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are not assigning the `#F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE` id to more than one element.

Ensure jQuery has finished initializing and that the `#F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE` element has been added to the dom:

```
$(function(){
    var meetingDate22 = $("input[name='F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE']").val();
    alert(meetingDate22);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work in your code below your context.

```
alert( document.getElementById('F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE').value);
```

That is use `id` not the `name`.If your attribute is name then it didn't work.

```
document.getElementsByName('F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE')[0].value)  //is work for your name.
```

Therefore, correct your code `$("#F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE")` instead of `$("input[name='F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE']")`

In addition, pure javascript would catch error if you set `id` is `F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE` and get the `F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE` of `name`.

Comment: The poster of the question mentioned that the id of the element is the same as its name (see comments on original question).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var meetingDate22 = $("input[name=F_GCEO_MEETING_DATE]").val();
alert(meetingDate22);
```

I think you should not use quotes after name